# (root) Additional property servicies is not allowed

Tags: mongodb, docker

When I try to do `docker compose up` this error show up:

> (root) Additional property servicies is not allowed

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

servicies:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        container_name: mongodb
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            -data:/data
        enviroment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootpass
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        container_name: mongo-express
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        enviroment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb volumes:
    data: {}
     networks:
    default:
        name: mongodb_network
```

I have recently installed docker so the version is the last one

Comment: `services` shouldn't have an extra `i` after the `c`.